# Jquery : Find and Copy text that as same as text in another div

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 divs

> **the first div**

```
<div id="a">author</div>
```

i want to copy text in the second div below that has text as same as text  in the first div above

> **the second div**

```
<div id="name">

  <span class="user">
    <a>author</a>
    <span class="count">4</span>
  </span>

  <span class="user">
    <a>car</a>
    <span class="count">10</span>
  </span>

</div>
```

and display to the third div

> **the third div**

```
<div id="result">
<div>
```

Result

```
<div id="result">
          <a>author</a>
          <span class="count">4</span>
<div>
```

Comment: Okay. Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) along with [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('#result').html($('#name .user:eq(0)').html());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FxThF/)**

Comment: Great the :eq selector! did not know this one!

Comment: i want to copy text like in this div <div id="a">author</div>,not the first text.

Comment: @PangeranZuckerberg what exactly the result do you want to achieve, please edit your question to elaborate, I'll try to help you more

Comment: @Felix I just edited the question. your code just copy the first text,i want the result is text that contains text like in the first div.

Comment: Can you show all the original code and the final expected result? Currently you separate it make me quite confused.

Comment: the result is "author 4" ,all the original code is in here http://jsfiddle.net/FxThF/2/

Comment: @Felix but how about this http://jsfiddle.net/FxThF/4/ ,the result is "car 10",i want the result is text that contains text like in the first div,not text is in the first span.

Comment: @Felix the result should be"author 4" , http://jsfiddle.net/FxThF/6/ just copy from #a and not display from #name span.